# Workoround for Room's FramworkSQLiteDatabase class that has gone protected in alpha-3?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am using the `FrameworkSQLiteDatabase` class in a SQLite helper ([this is pretty much the code](https://github.com/CaMnter/AndroidLife/blob/d397ab96629637c9de0a7f5cda98ef091893cf2e/room/src/main/java/alpha1/android/arch/persistence/db/framework/FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java)) for Room.

I now tried to update Room from `alpha-1` to `alpha-3` and Gradle build fails saying that the `FrameworkSQLiteDatabase` is not accessible from my code, which is actually true: they kept the constructor `public` but they made the class `protected` (and that seems the only change they've made).

I'm pretty new to Room and I was wondering if there was any API or method to get over this problem.

Thanks a lot in advance guys!

Comment: You could create a `public` do-nothing subclass in `android.arch.persistence.db.framework`, then use your subclass, perhaps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry but I think I'm missing out on something. How can I create this public class in a third party library that I'm getting via Gradle? I thought this was not possible...

Comment: The library is third-party. However, `android.arch.persistence.db.framework` is just a string. You can create in  your project that package and put a class there. Though, now that I think about it, if it is `protected`, you could put your subclass in any package. I was thinking about package-private classes, where your subclass would need to be in that specific package (`android.arch.persistence.db.framework` in this case).